Refused to frame 'my-domain.com/' because an ancestor violates the following Content Security Policy directive
I'm trying to display in my Angular app some website using HTML <iframe> Tag,
When I open the url path through Postman it works great But when I try to display the site by transferring the url path using HTML <iframe> Tag, I get the following error:

Refused to frame 'https://us-east-2.quicksight.aws.amazon.com/'
because an ancestor violates the following Content Security Policy
directive: "frame-ancestors 'self' https://* http://*".

According to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CSP I need to add inside my index.html the following code:
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy"
   content="default-src 'self'; img-src https://*; child-src 'none';" />

When ive add this code my app is broken, what am i missing?
Attach fully index.html file
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8"/>
  <title>My app</title>
  <base href="/"/>
  <meta
    name="viewport"
    content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"
  />
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy"
        content="default-src 'self'; img-src https://*; child-src 'none';"/>
  <link
    rel="icon"
    type="image"
    href="assets/logo.svg"
  />

  <link
    rel="preconnect"
    href="https://fonts.gstatic.com"
  />
  <link
    href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:wght@300;400;500&display=swap"
    rel="stylesheet"
  />
  <link
    href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons"
    rel="stylesheet"
  />
</head>
<body>
<app-root></app-root>
</body>
</html>

